# What is this frog I found

Tags: species-identification, zoology, herpetology

What type of frog or toad is this? I found him in my backyard in southern Alabama and he is clearly very small. I’m not sure what species it is, it’s mostly brown but has small spots on the top of his mouth and under his eyes and he is completely white on his belly. Anyone have any idea what this little guy is?[image]